# How to display data horizontally in rdlc report?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I want to display data in **rdlc** report as shown in image.

I am getting vertically data like a list. But I want to display horizontally.
Please give the solution with snaps.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that tablixes in different groups or add different groups
2. Check the size of your tables and page size. Is table size bigger than page size.
3. Add more information, i cant help you without it.

[image]